# Ghostscript command convert pdf into large JPGE File

Tags: pdf, jpeg, ghostscript

I have a ghostscript command that converts a pdf into several JPG images (one for every page). The command arguments are as follows:

```
-q -dUseCropBox  -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -dBATCH -dDOINTERPOLATE -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dPrinted=false -r250 -sDEVICE=jpeg  -dJPEGQ=100  -sOutputFile=output.jpg  input.pdf -c quit
```

The pdf  size is 1.5mb but in the JPGE images it becomes huge (~15MB) with dimension 8829 *15551

if I change the resolution in the ghostscript command to -r150 the page size is correct but the image quality is very rastorized.

Is there another way to decrease the image size of the image without affecting the image quality?

Thanks

Comment: PDF has two page with high Definition image so PDF is fully image based. You cann't move to PNG format It's requirement

Comment: If the original PDF has high resolution JPEG images, the you should just extract those and use them. Decompressing and recompressing JPEGs will cause compression artefacts. This is not 'rastorized', its caused by the compression, an image is already rasterised. Of course, without seeing an example its not really possible to give you any firm reccomendations.